# SQL Server binary(128) convert from little endian to big endian

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, endianness

how to convert a binary(128) from  little endian to big endian in SQL Server?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try something like this:

```
declare @little binary(4)
set @little = 0x02010000

select
  @little [bigEndian],
  cast(reverse(@little) as binary(4)) [littleEndian]
```

OUTPUT:

```
bigEndian  littleEndian
---------- ------------
0x02010000 0x00000102

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: what if i wanted to reverse the bytes? not sure if reversing bytes is the same as changing from big to little and vice versa. What if i wanted to reverse the bytes from 0x00000102 to 0x00000201 staying in little endian i guess?

Comment: In this case you'd need to be careful about the length of your values: SELECT cast(reverse(cast(0x0102 AS BINARY(4))) AS BINARY(4))

Comment: how would you go about comparing a @@dbts timestamp saved as varbinary(8) against a varbinary(8) in a little endian based architecture? @@dbts I believe is big endian which will have to be converted to little endian before comparison?

Comment: If you have a hex string like `1f100000` remember to cast it to `BINARY` before calling reverse. Calling `reverse()` on the string won't give the little-endian. This answer worked for me after I remembered to correct my types.