# How Binary Data is represented in SQL database

Tags: sql-server

I have a field named X where the fieldtype is Binary(15). 
Now I am updating the table with

```
Update Table_name 
Set X = 567845329090989
Where some_condition
```

Now after executing the above command in the table while viewing I am seeing that the column is updated with the following

```
0x0000000F000001ADB920CB73040200
```

This is not Hexadecimal value also. How is this working?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? You would use `0x567845329090989` if you wanted it treated as literal binary data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 567845329090989 is <strike>bigint</strike> decimal(15,0)
- using Windows calculator, this is 0x20473CB20B9AD
- the value above is 0x0000000F000001 **ADB920CB730402** 00

I forget exact details but it's to [do with endianess (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416557/sql-server-binary128-convert-from-little-endian-to-big-endian)

Comment: Thanks but What does Binary (15) exactly means? 15 Byte space of data?

Answer (score 2):

From comment by @gbn. The constant `567845329090989` is read as decimal(15,0) not bigint.

```
declare @T table (X binary(15))

declare @X bigint = 567845329090989
declare @Y decimal(15,0) = 567845329090989

insert into @T values (@X)
insert into @T values (567845329090989)
insert into @T values (@Y)

select *
from @T
```

Result

```
X
--------------------------------
0x0000000000000000020473CB20B9AD
0x0000000F000001ADB920CB73040200
0x0000000F000001ADB920CB73040200
```

Comment: Interesting. The one using a constant gets compiled into the plan as `[Expr1004] = Scalar Operator(0x0000000F000001ADB920CB73040200)` The one using a variable is `[Expr1004] = Scalar Operator(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(binary(15),[@X],0))` Not obvious to me why the one with the constant should be treated differently. Ah gbn's update about `decimal(15,0)` explains it.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. 567845329090989 is read as decimal(15,0) which converts differently to bigint